# Rails string to DOB year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently storing strings formatted like "01/01/1989" (client side validation) for the bday field.

I want to parse out the year and store it as a variable, like this:

```
@bdayyear = current_user.bday.year
```

I want that to bring back "1989"

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do using [`#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) and [`::strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) :

```
s = "01/01/1989"
current_user.bday.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y")
# => "1989"
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a `DateTime` object and you can call year on it

```
>> DateTime.parse("01/01/1989").year
=> 1989
```

Comment: parse won't always work with mm/dd/yyy style dates because I believe it implies dd/mm/yyyy so "12/13/1989" will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always consistent the why not just use the string

```
"01/01/1989".slice(-4..-1)
"01/01/1989"[-4..-1]
```

Or

```
"01/01/1989".split(/\W/).pop
```

These will all return "1989" without converting it to a date